# Where to find eclipse source that was in cvs or is in subversion?

Tags: eclipse, e4

I am ultimately trying to follow this page:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/Running_the_demos

But, some of the project sets refer to paths in CVS that no longer exist, or have been moved. For example org.eclipse.swt. I don't see org.eclipse.swt in git, but I see it in subversion here:

http://dev.eclipse.org/viewsvn/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt/

So, it exists, but how can I retrieve it, other than file by file from viewvc?

I could write a script. But, someone somewhere knows how to get at the files that are being served above. Are you one of those people?

Mote that I am not asking where to find org.eclipse.swt. Given a path to eclipse source that is in subversion, where can I checkout that source?

Answer (score 0):

The CVS archive is still there, but I'm not sure the anonymous CVS access method defined right next to the "Where can I get this?" will connect any more.  Everything's either in SVN (http://wiki.eclipse.org/SVN_Howto) or more likely Git (http://git.eclipse.org/c/) these days.

Comment: I am ultimately trying to fix a project set file for a project that is in git (E4 demos). It refers to paths in CVS that don't exist. The projects aren't in git, or are named differently. The SVN howto refers to the path /svnroot that doesn't exist.   I see at least one of the projects in viewsvn. So, my question is, where can I checkout those files?

Comment: Err. Oh. viewsvn is displaying a cvs repository. Even so, there is no /cvsroot/eclipse.                     So, I've revised my question: Where is viewsvn pointing if it is not /cvsroot/eclipse?

Comment: The SVN Howto I linked to lists all of the SVN repos.  Everything else is in Git.